# transformed coordinates negated and in wrong order

Tags: ros, image-geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the example code here: http://wiki.ros.org/image_geometry/Tutorials/ProjectTfFrameToImage
... to project object positions from gazebo into an image frame.

To get it to work correctly, I had to introduce a horribly hack - negating and rearranging the order of the coordinations on line 63:

- ```
     cv::Point3d pt_cv(pt.x(), pt.y(), pt.z());
  ```

- ```
     cv::Point3d pt_cv(-pt.y(), -pt.z(), pt.x());
  ```

Obviously, this is less than satisfactory, and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong up stream. Any suggestions as to how I might identify the source of the problem would be very much appreciated.

cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216573/transformed-coordinates-negated-and-in-wrong-order/) by [lteacy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1940/lteacy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks very much like you're mixing up the camera frame and the optical frame. They are two different coordinate systems. Usually a driver launch script (e.g. for kinect) provides the transformation between both. If you apply that it will perform your horrible hack in a controlled manner.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lteacy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1940/lteacy/) on 2015-08-28**:
works now - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds a lot like a mix-up between the ROS standard frame convention and the special convention used for optical frames as described in [REP-0103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#suffix-frames) (look at the "suffix frames") part. Normally, the setup with two frames for a camera allows easy conversion via tf.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lteacy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1940/lteacy/) on 2015-08-28**:
Many thanks to both - this does appear to the be the issue. Works perfectly now (without the hack ;-)